# Kibana doesn’t update properly once filebeat is stopped for sometime

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

In my ELK setup, when filebeat is stopped for sometime, Kibana starts updating from the timestamp where the filebeat is started. No data available(under Discover tab) for the filebeat not functioning timeframe. Once filebeat is started, there are spikes in "Discover" tab initially which means data is updated under wrong time stamp.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because some component (probably Logstash) is adding `@timestamp`, on the moment of sending the data to Elasticsearch. The solution: add `@timestamp` at the source, and don't overwrite it.

You can add a `@timestamp` value with a Filebeat [Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/processor-timestamp.html), or in [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html), or by adding a valid `@timestamp` to your logs from the source and logging directly in JSON, foregoing any regex/grok or Processors.

Whichever way you use, you have to go through the pipeline to make sure it does not tamper with `@timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I'll check this and get back to you.